# Can laser diode characteristics comparison be based on laser of one length?

Tags: optics, semiconductor-physics, laser, experimental-technique, photonics

As we know, e.g. [from this website](https://www.laserdiodecontrol.com/laser-diode-parameter-overview), to know the laser Transparency Threshold Current and Internal Quantum Efficiency, we need the LI curves from lasers of various widths.

However sometimes it is infeasible to manufacture diodes with various cavity lengths.

But, if one can obtain diodes of the same length, but with different semiconductor materials, can one make a justifiable comparison between those diodes?

For example "Diode from material A has better slope efficiency than same-length diode of material B, thus material A will provide better quantum efficiency". Is such statement physically justifiable?

Here to an existing figure I added a hypothetical line that might correspond to laser A. For some lengths, we have points with better B efficiency, and for some other lengths, laser A performs better. But in the end, laser A has higher IQE. Do such deceiving situations happen in laser diodes?

I'm asking because in many publications I saw, researchers are happy with a single-cavity-length measurement and comparison. Are they incompetent, or do they know something I don't?

[image]